# Rails number_with_delimiter return integer without delimiter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, number-with-delimiter

I'm usually using `number_with_delimiter` to make my integer or my decimal more easy to read, I have once problem with it when using it inside controller but it solved that time. Now I don't know what happen actually when I just simply put those function on my `view` it return `integer` **without** `delimiter`.

Please see this simulation I create to show the different.

```
<td><%= number_to_currency(stock.qty) %></td>
<td><%= (number_with_delimiter number_with_precision stock.qty, :precision => 2) %></td>
<td><%= number_with_delimiter(stock.qty) %></td>
<td><%= stock.qty %></td>
```

Result:

```
$100,070.00    100070    100070    100070.0
```

So the `number_with_delimiter` and `number_with_precision` isn't working also. The thing also is it just happen to this project while the others projects on my *local* all doing fine. And also on my other branch of this project also fine. So I know that there is something I broke into. But I don't know which one it is, since I also didn't realize and didn't know which one I make it broken, I can't trace through my version control cause there is too much update on it. Please any help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying the delimiter with `:delimiter => ","`?

Comment: The result with `:delimiter => ","` is `10,0070` while the value from database is `10007.00000` hahaha how could is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @tomanow that lead me to the expected result. So in the end I used there code:

Located on my **application_helper.rb**

```
def delimiter(number)
  number_with_delimiter(number, :delimiter => ",", :separator => ".")
end
```

And use it everywhere. Thanks